# How do I restrict a Flask App running on Windows 10 with nginx and uwsgi using docker-compose.yml to a specific custom domain?

Tags: windows, flask, nginx, docker-compose, uwsgi

I have a simple Flask app running on Windows 10 using nginx, uwsgi, and a docker-compose.yml file. My Dockerfile is using this container image: `tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.11`.

I'm trying to restrict it to running on a specific custom domain on my local machine, `site1.test`. It seems to run on any custom domains I make.

In my docker-compose.yml file I have the following:

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  # define our services

  flask:

    build: ./flask

    container_name: flask

    restart: always

    environment:
      - APP_NAME=MyFlaskApp
        VIRTUAL_HOST: site1.test
        VIRTUAL_PORT: 3000

    expose:
      - 8080

    volumes:
      - ./log/uwsgi:/var/log/uwsgi

  nginx:

    build: ./nginx

    container_name: nginx

    restart: always

    ports:
      - "80:80"

    volumes:
      - ./log/nginx:/var/log/nginx

  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
```

The last service, `nginx-proxy`, was added today along with the `VIRTUAL_HOST` and `VIRTUAL_PORT` variables in the flask service's `environment` in an effort to restrict the app running ON AND ONLY ON `site1.test` locally; it didn't work. I also added the following to my `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 site1.test
```

My `nginx.conf` file looks like this:

```
server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass flask:8080;
    }

}
```

My app loads when I type `site1.test` in my browser. If I keep the host file the same and change the flask service's enironment `VIRTUAL_HOST` to something different, like `site25.test`, my app still loads on `site1.test`. I'm trying to restrict my app to a particular custom domain.

What am I doing wrong?

In addition to adding what I did in the `docker-compose.yml` file, I had a block in `nginx.conf` that tried using a `server site1.test`, and also `server_name site1.test` when that didn't work. I also tried adding both

```
127.0.0.1 site1.test
127.0.0.1 site25.test
```

to my `hosts` file, in hopes that with more than a single custom domain listed, it might only work on one. However, then my app just loads on both domains.